No options for type of installation in installing ubuntu
I have Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to fresh install Ubuntu 24.04. In the installation process I selected Full installation and checked install third-party software and download additional media codecs. Logically I expected to see the option to Erase the disk and install Ubuntu or Manual installation, but neither of these options were shown. (the page is blank and next button is deactivated) I thought I should wait, but waiting didn't do any good. I thought I could install Ubuntu 23.10 then upgrade it to 24.04, but the 23.10 installation also has the same issue.

I am currently in Ubuntu live 23.10 and this is the picture from the installation window. All the mentioned versions are desktop installations.

Please be precise with details; there is no Ubuntu 23, so what exactly are you using?  Ubuntu 23.04? or Ubuntu 23.10?   Do you mean Ubuntu Core 22 when you say Ubuntu 22? as the year format is used for the snap only versions of Ubuntu Server.  FYI:   If you do mean Ubuntu 23.10; there are three installers (ubuntu-desktop-installer, subiquity and ubiquity where you select at download time (ISO choice) which you'll use.. so specifics help).

by 24 I mean 24.04 and for 23 I mean 23.10. It is the desktop installer

Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop has two ISOs offered at download; the primary ISO uses the ubuntu-desktop-installer (ie. same installer used in 24.04), where as the legacy ISO of Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop uses the ubiquity installer (default of 22.10 & earlier; 23.04 having the same choices as 23.10).  Two desktop installer options exist for 23.10 Desktop.
